# Prove that if a|b and b|c then a|c using a column proof that has steps in the first column and the reason for the step in the second column.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

**Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be integers, where a $\ne$ 0. Then
$$
$$
(i) if $a$ | $b$ and $a$ | $c$, then $a$ | ($b+c$)
$$
$$
(ii) if $a$ | $b$ then $a$|$bc$ for all integers $c$;
$$
$$
(iii) if $a$ |$b$ and $b$|$c$, then $a$|$c$.**

**Prove that if $a$|$b$ and $b$|$c$ then $a$|$c$ using a column proof that has steps in the first column
and the reason for the step in the second column.**

My book is really vague. I'm not really sure what to do..

First I was thinking something like this: $a\mid b\Rightarrow b=as$ and  $b\mid c\Rightarrow c=bt$ and $a\mid c\Rightarrow c = au$
$$
$$
$b + c + c = b + 2c$ 
$$
$$
$=as + 2(bt+au)$

Yea then I just got lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use fractions then all inferences are immediate consequences of the fact that $\,\Bbb Z\,$ is closed under addition and multiplication - see below. If you are not allowed to use fractions then you can translate the below proofs to integers by clearing denominators, e.g. for $(i)$ we get $\ b=aj,\, c = ak\,\Rightarrow\, a(j + k) = b + c$

$( i)\quad \dfrac{b}a,\,\dfrac{c}a\in\Bbb Z\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{c}a = \dfrac{b+c}{a}\in\Bbb Z$

$(ii)\quad \dfrac{b}a,\ c\in\Bbb Z\ \Rightarrow\ c\, \dfrac{b}a = \dfrac{cb}a\in\Bbb Z$

$(iii)\ \ \ \dfrac{b}a,\,\dfrac{c}b\in\Bbb Z\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{b}a\dfrac{c}b = \dfrac{c}a\in\Bbb Z$

Note: $ $ if $\,b=0\,$ is allowed in $\,(iii)\,$ then you need to consider that case too.

Answer (score 1):

See this 
$$ a|b \implies b = ma \quad \rm and \quad  a|c \implies c=na, \quad m,n \in \mathbb{Z}  $$

which gives us

$$ b+c = (m+n)a = p a \implies a|(b+c),\quad p=n+m \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

Comment: isn't that exactly the same as the proof for $(i)$....? proof $(i)$ says that $a$|$(b+c)$ so is proof $(iii)$ just another way of saying the same thing?

Comment: You have a good start but as you said in your question "you got lost"!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$, then

1) if $a\mid b$ we can write $b=a\cdot k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Similarly for $c$ we can say that $c=a\cdot l$ for some $l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Now multiplication distributes over addition we have $b+c=ak+al=a(k+l)$ which is obviously divisible by $a$ since it has $a$ as a factor.

2) if $a\mid b$ then $b=a\cdot k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $bc=akc=a(kc)$ since multplication is associative and the last expression is clearly divisible by $a$.

3) if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ so we can write $b=ka, \ k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $c=bl,\  l \in\mathbb{Z}$. Combining these two gives $c=bl=(ka)l=(ak)l=a(kl)$ since multiplication is both commutative and associative. The last expression is clearly divisible by $a$.

Answer (score -1):

According to the definition of division,
$b=as$  and $c=bt$

$$bc=asbt$$

$$c=\frac{asbt}b$$

$c=a(st) \implies s$ and $t$ are integers which makes $st$ also an integer
this means $a|c$