# Notation question: $\mid $

Tags: notation

I have the following problem:

In this problem all variables range over $Z$, the set of all integers.

a. Prove that if $a \mid b$ and $a \mid c$, then $a\mid (b + c)$.

b. Prove that if $ac \mid bc$, and $c \neq 0$, then $a \mid b$.

This question has basically been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175728/prove-that-if-ab-and-bc-then-ac-using-a-column-proof-that-has-steps-in-the-fi). I just literally do not know what the vertical bar "$\mid$" means and somehow I can't find this information anywhere.

The best solution I can find is that it means "nand" in the context of boolean logic, e.g. $P\mid Q$ means $P$ and $Q$ are not both true. However this doesn't seem particularly relevant for integers.

Anything helps, thank you!

Comment: As Patrick Stevens said, it means "divides", but you can also think of $a \mid b$ to mean that $a$ is factor of $b$.

Answer (score 5):

It means "divides".

$a \mid b$ iff there is $c$ such that $a \times c = b$.

Comment: Thank you! To clarify, this would be equivalent to b/a or a/b? I'm thinking b/a by the literal translation of "divides" but I want to make sure.

Comment: No. Vertical bar `|` is completely different from the division symbol `/`

Comment: "$a \mid b$" is a statement which is either true or false; $a / b$ is a number which could be e.g. $3$ or $9$.

Comment: Oh I understand, thank you.

Comment: As an example, "$7\mid 21$" is true because $7$ is a factor of $21$.  However $7/21 = 0.3333\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

It’s important to realize that in the *sentence* “$a\mid b$”, the vertical bar is the verb. Thus this sentence “$a|b$” is either true or false, depending on whether there is an integer $m$ for which $b=ma$. There is no numerical value, just, if you like, a boolean value. Some true sentences are $3\mid 12$, $3\mid 0$, and $0\mid 0$. Some false sentences are $3\mid 5$ and $0\mid 5$.